# how to detect form data change?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have  a form with a lot of textboxes. I am trying to loop controls in the form to detect if the textbox, combobox changes before closing the form  but I cannot get it to work.

Below is the code I am referring to:

```
 public partial class PatientFiles : Form, ILookup
 {
    bool NeedSaving = false;

    void CheckChanges(Control.ControlCollection cc)
    {
       foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
       {
          MaskedTextBox mtxtBox = ctrl as MaskedTextBox;
          TextBox txtBox = ctrl as TextBox;
          ComboBox cmb = ctrl as ComboBox;

          mtxtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextWasChanged);
          txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextWasChanged);
          cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextWasChanged);
          //CheckChanges(ctrl.Controls);

       }

    }

    //formload
    private void frmPatient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       EnableNavigation();
       //txtEngName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextWasChanged);
       CheckChanges(this.Controls);

    }` 

    public void TextWasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       NeedSaving = true;
   }`

   private void PatientFiles_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       //NeedSaving();
       // Disable Navigation On Form closing
       if (NeedSaving)
       {

           DialogResult dt = MessageBox.Show("Save Changes", "information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
           if (dt == DialogResult.Yes)
           {
               SaveData();
               //DisableNavigation();
           }

           else if (dt == DialogResult.No)
           {

               DisableNavigation();
               NeedSaving = false;
               this.Close();
           }
           else if (dt == DialogResult.Cancel)
               e.Cancel = true;
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Define "but not work".  When you debug this, how is it failing?  Does `cc` contain the controls you expect?  Are the events being added to the controls?  Where does this fail?

Comment: Did you get any error?. Do you see 'TextWasChanged' assigned on the properties window as event handler fot TextChanged event?

Comment: Your code assumes every control is a MaskedTextBox, a TextBox, and a ComboBox.  You need to check which control you currently have.  This would also not work if any of those controls were inside another panel, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `CheckChanges` is incorrect. You should check for nullabillity of casted controls

```
void CheckChanges(Control.ControlCollection cc)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
    {
        MaskedTextBox mtxtBox = ctrl as MaskedTextBox;
        if (mtxtBox != null)
            mtxtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextWasChanged);

        TextBox txtBox = ctrl as TextBox;
        if (txtBox != null)
            txtBox.TextChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextWasChanged);

        ComboBox cmb = ctrl as ComboBox;
        if (cmb != null)
            cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.TextWasChanged);
        //CheckChanges(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What doesn't work?

I see that if someone changes the text back to the original value your property NeedSaving remains true.

Why not use the Tag property of each control to remember the original value and check upon exiting if the current value differs from the original one. Advantage: works with every control in your control collection, not just textboxes, maskedtextboxes etc.

```
private void frmPatient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var myControls = cc.Where(c => c is MaskedTextBox || c is TextBox || ...
   foreach (var control in myControls)
   {
       control.Tag = cc.Text;
   }
}

private void PatientFiles_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    bool anythingChanged = cc
        .Where( (c => c is MaskedTextBox || c is TextBox || ...) 
                  && (String.Equals(control.Text, control.Tag.ToString(), ...)
        .Any();
}
```

Stops as soon as the first element in the collection has a changed text.

Disadvantage: you can't visually feedback that anything has been changed. For that use event TextChanged.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine but form load beginning slow

```
foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
        {
            MaskedTextBox mtxtBox = ctrl as MaskedTextBox;
            if (mtxtBox != null)
                mtxtBox.TextChanged += TextWasChanged;

            TextBox txtBox = ctrl as TextBox;
            if (txtBox != null)
                txtBox.TextChanged += TextWasChanged;

            ComboBox cmb = ctrl as ComboBox;
            if (cmb != null)
                cmb.SelectedIndexChanged += TextWasChanged;
            CheckChanges(ctrl.Controls);
        }
```

Comment: How many controls do you have on the form?